# class data add will rewrite the data already exists

Tags: c#, sql, class, dataset, sqldatareader

I have a class and in 2 foreach loop I want to add all the data in tables in my dataset to my class but the problem is that: after it finishes the inner foreach loop, the next table that is going to be copied will also replace the records already in `ret` so inthe end if I have 2 tables of table1 of 1 rows and table 2 of 2 rows I will have 3 records in `ret` but all the data in table 1 are replaced with the data in table2!
example

table 1                          table 2
--------                         --------
v    y                           v     y
--  --                           --    --
te   st                          mm    dd
                                 ss    cc

but in the end in ret instead of having {te  st}{mm  dd}{ss cc} I have {mm  dd}{mm  dd}{ss cc} I have 
HELP!

```
list<class> ret = new list<class>();
class FR = new class();

foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FR.v) || FR.v != row["v"])
        {
            FR.v = row["v"].ToString();
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FR.y) || FR.y != row["y"])
        {
            FR.y = row["y"].ToString();
        }

        ret.Add(FR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FR` is always the same instance, so every time you set values on it you're operating on that same instance and re-adding it to the collection over and over.

Just create a new instance with each iteration of the loop:

```
List<SomeClass> ret = new List<SomeClass>();

foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        SomeClass FR = new SomeClass(); // <--- right here

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FR.v) || FR.v != row["v"])
        {
            FR.v = row["v"].ToString();
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FR.y) || FR.y != row["y"])
        {
            FR.y = row["y"].ToString();
        }

        ret.Add(FR);
    }
}
```

Comment: but in this case everytime it would be reset? I need to add all the data in all the tables in 1 class

Comment: @lol: You're mixing up some terminology, which makes your description difficult to follow.  Each instance will be of the same class, since it's declared as the same type every time.  Or do you mean that you want all of the data to somehow be in *one instance* of the class?  In which case it's not clear at all what the problem is or even what you're trying to do, really.

Comment: I just updated my question, would you please read it. thanks a lot

Comment: @lol: That update doesn't really clarify anything.  But did you try my answer?  It really sounds like you're just trying to combine these tables into a single collection of objects.  In what way does the code in my answer not accomplish that?